# Git pull without specific file

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, github, bitbucket

I`m running my application on AWS and I manage my source code in bitbucket.
When I tried to git pull, I got this error...

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    Gemfile.lock
    config/database.yml
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

What I want to  do is to git pull without rewriting this two file. Gemfile.lock and config/database.yml and update another file.

Comment: use `git stash` to stash away your local changes and then pull from the remote repository.

Comment: I may be wrong, but if you just delete those two files and pull you might be OK.  I clearly recall having problems in the past with recalcitrant lock files, and deleting them fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I would commit the changes to another branch using the following method. First:

```
$ git stash
```

stash the changes to the two files that are likely to be overwritten

```
$ git checkout -b <newbranch>
$ git stash apply
$ git commit -m 'this branch contains my original files'
```

make a new branch, apply the changes you made, then commit them to the new branch

```
$ git checkout <old branch>
$ git pull
```

Check out your old branch, and pull the changes. You can then investigate the changed files by looking at them in the different branches, and you can merge oldbranch into newbranch if necessary.